# Strong name validation failure exception in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, strongname

I have a project solution in VS 2005 in which there is one web application in asp.net and couple of libraries written in c# which are used by the web application.  We are using all dll/exe of solution project signed with strong name in their project properties.

Now when we build the whole solution and try to run the web application through the asp development server on IE browser, it throws the following exception:

> Strong name validation failed for assembly 'abc.dll'. The file may have been tampered with or it was partially signed but not fully signed with the correct private key.

So please help me how we can overcome to this problem.

Thanks,
Ajit

Answer (score 1):

Hai ajit,

Have a look these links

http://www.nirsoft.net/dot_net_tools/strong_name_remove.html

http://p2p.wrox.com/asp-net-1-0-1-1-basics/8730-strong-name-validation-failed.html

http://www.outsystems.com/NetworkForums/ViewTopic.aspx?Topic=Strong-name-validation-failed-for-assembly-...

http://dbaspot.com/forums/ms-sqlserver/218670-strong-name-exception-when-calling-stronly-named-assembly.html

or try changing **compile option to not use
delayed signing.**

Answer (score 0):

Do you  know for sure that the assembly abc.dll is signed?